# Constant Contact two forms on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using Constant Contact to create a signup form on our site.
I want to have the form show in the header and in the footer.

Here's the javascript that I need to include in the page in order for the form to work https://static.ctctcdn.com/h/contacts-embedded-signup-assets/1.0.2/js/signup-form.js

The issue is that if I submit the top form, then whatever response the server gives, it gets displayed by both forms.

If the server returns an error, the javascript prints the error twice.

how can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK to implement this for your form add a unique class name to each form (i.e. top bottom popup), and then call your main function for each

```
  main(jQuery,'top');
  main(jQuery,'bottom');
  main(jQuery,'mpopup');
```

and edit your main function like this

```
function main($, position) {
    .....
    var _form = $('.'+ position +'[data-id="embedded_signup:form"]');
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the server side validation of the form completes, the results are displayed on the form that was assigned to the _form variable on line 24
  *var _form = $('[data-id="embedded_signup:form"]');*

I recommend retrieving forms from the dom seperately and modify main() to allow the passing of the form that should be connected.

```
function hookForms(){
    var f1 =document.querySelector('#myform1');
    var f2 =document.querySelector('#myform2');
    main(jQuery,f1);
    main(jQuery,f2);
} 
hookForms();
```

The first lines in main should be changed to

```
function main($, form) {
   $.support.cors = true;
   if (typeof postURL === 'undefined') {
       postURL = 'https://visitor2.constantcontact.com/api/signup';
   }
   var _form = form;
```

The hookForms function would replace the calls to main shown on lines 12 and 16. This has not been tested, however providing only one form element should only give the main function and the xhs callback access to change the one form that was passed (if you call main again with a second form, the interactions of those forms are treated seperately.). Note: if response for one form is successfully completed only that form will change to state the signup completed. I am not sure how this will affect the redirect.

If your intention is to hide only the validation messages, then you could identify both forms to the main function and locate them exactly how the script is working now without modification, then pass the element making the post call from the onsubmit attribute with "this" onsubmit="javascript:sendForm(this)" and make some minor adjustments to reference the form that submitted the request when the validation messages are displayed.

You may be able to do this with just one form, using a css pop-up and a link from your header and footer, then you will not have to edit the script.

Comment: thanks! so I should make a local copy of their JS and call that one instead in my forms?

Comment: Yes, also change the attributes in the html for the two forms so they have unique id selectors. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tugg56so/ is my local js (the top of it) and the forms both work but instead of returning the validation inline (success or error) it opens a new tab with the json response

Comment: The fiddle did not have the html and only showed part of the script.

Because this is loading cors json, a fiddle may not be able to complete the task. Did you run from the fiddle or locally on you own server?